# PHP JSON Decode with number

Tags: php, json, decode

I want to display some information from the API https://steamgaug.es/api/v2 on my website.

This is my current code:

```
 $steamStatusJson = @file_get_contents("https://steamgaug.es/api/v2");
 $steamStatus = json_decode($steamStatusJson);
 $csgoStatus = $steamStatus->ISteamGameCoordinator->730->online;
 $csgoplayerssearching = $steamStatus->ISteamGameCoordinator->730->stats->players_searching;
 $csgoplayers =  $steamStatus->ISteamGameCoordinator->730->stats->players_online;
```

I always get this error message:

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '730' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as lone as you are decoding your json as an object, you can not use numbers as a [properties names](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

so, you need to this line :

```
$csgoStatus = $steamStatus->ISteamGameCoordinator->730->online;
```

should be as follows :

```
$csgoStatus = $steamStatus->ISteamGameCoordinator->{"730"}->online;
//                                                 ^^^^^^^
```

also the same with those lines :

```
$csgoplayerssearching = $steamStatus->ISteamGameCoordinator->{"730"}->stats->players_searching;
$csgoplayers =  $steamStatus->ISteamGameCoordinator->{"730"}->stats->players_online;
```

or, simply by decoding your json as an array

```
$steamStatus = json_decode($steamStatusJson, true);
```

and then you can access it as :

```
$csgoStatus = $steamStatus['ISteamGameCoordinator']['730']['online'];
//....
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank  you very much